# Android Studio: german chars not displayed correctly

Tags: android, android-studio

I imported an Android project from Eclipse to Android studio and (almost) everything went surprisingly except for one thing:

Android Studio or better: the resulting app seems to have some trouble with german chars like 
ÜÖÄß.

This is from my `Manifest`:

```
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.myapp.SomeActivity"
        android:label="Registrierung abschließen">
```

and this is how the `Activity`'s `ActionBar` looks like:

[image]

I have similar kind of troubles with `.html` files in my `/res/raw` folder.

Any ideas on this?

Comment: That's UTF-8 interpreted as ISO-8859-x. Check your XML file encoding, both the encoding you save as and the encoding you possibly declare at the top of the file.

Comment: Thanks, this gave me the right direction. Setting <?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?> fixed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use in your xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

Comment: Thanks, this gave me the right direction. Setting <?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?> fixed it.